# How to bulk update records with foreach?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, foreach

I got a foreach loop to fetch the stored values on the DB and display each of them, it's working fine, but now I want to bulk update it's value, here is my code to generate the checkboxes.

```
@foreach ($servers as $server)

    <input type="checkbox" name="servidor[]" value="status_on" {{$server->status == 1 ? 'checked' : ''}}>

@endforeach
```

And here is my code to update the values on DB.

```
foreach (request('servidor') as $update) {

    DB::table('servers')
    ->where('id', $update)
    ->update(['status' => $update->servidor]);

}
```

It's not working, I keep getting:

> Trying to get property of non-object

On this line: `->update(['status' => $update->servidor]);`

How can I bulk update these dynamically generated checkboxes?

Comment: You're using `$update` as the id as well as the object you're getting status from, is it an integer or an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get server_id=>value array you should change the input checkbox as

```
<input type="checkbox" name="servidor[{{$server->id}}]" value="{{$server->status}}" {{$server->status == 1 ? 'checked' : ''}}><span></span>
```

so you can make server id->value array and then use foreach($value as $key => $value) and your problem will be solved.

Comment: You wll get a $key as server's id and $value as server's value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it working, my final code was this: https://pastebin.com/yvd0X4YV *

Comment: you're weclome :) @Vinny

Answer (score 0):

Print out the values of the object $update as

```
 print_r(update) or var_dump(update) to see the $update objects
```

then change that line as

```
>update(['status' => $update->CORRECT-ITEM-FROM-ABOVE-PRINT-OUT]);
```

ps: Looking back at your above code looks like the logic is wrong.
You want set the 'server->status' to "someValue" and in that loop "someValue" is wrong.

```
->update(['status' => $update->servidor]);
```

Comment: I got this ```Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1)```

Comment: ```print_r($update[0] . "<br>");``` returns: ```1<br>1<br>```

Comment: I updated the answer, i don't see any meaningful value for right side of that assignment. What value do you expect for server status to be set to?

Comment: It must be set to 0 or 1, the problem is that the form is sending only one value for each checkbox, it should send the checkbox value along with the server id in the same array object.

Comment: According to the above print out the print_r($update[0] ) returns 1. Not sure what this returns print_r($update[1]. check out that

Comment: Does the value 1 make sense for server status? in your project